# Libgdx iterating speeding up animation?

Tags: java, libgdx

GitHub: https://github.com/alex578344/RocketDefender.git

In my render loop I iterate through a series of rockets and when i click on them a explosion animation is shown. The problem is the animation is too quick and how however i change the float value for the run time of the Animation it seems to still show at the same really quick speed.

```
  textureAtlas = new TextureAtlas(Gdx.files.internal("ExplosionAnimation.atlas"));
        explosionA = new Animation(10f, textureAtlas.getRegions());
```

---

```
 public void render(float runTime){

        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        cam.update();

        batch.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);

        batch.begin();
        //BATCH START


        batch.draw(AssetLoader.background, 0, 0 , GWidth,GHeight);

        for(Rectangle rocket : rockets) {
            batch.draw(AssetLoader.rocket ,rocket.x, rocket.y,
                    rocket.width, rocket.height);
        }

        if (Gdx.input.justTouched()){

            Vector3 v = new Vector3(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY(), 0);
            v = cam.unproject(v);

            tap_X = (int) v.x;
            tap_Y = (int) v.y;

            Gdx.app.log("MyTag", String.valueOf(tap_X));
            Gdx.app.log("MyTag", String.valueOf(tap_Y));



        }

        Iterator<Rectangle> iter = rockets.iterator();
        while(iter.hasNext()) {

            Rectangle rocket = iter.next();
            rocket.y -= 140 * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
            if(rocket.y + 32 < 0) iter.remove();

            if (rocket.x - 5 < tap_X && tap_X < rocket.x + rocket.width + 5) {

                if (tap_Y > rocket.y - 5 && tap_Y < rocket.y + rocket.height + 5) {
                    batch.draw(AssetLoader.explosionA.getKeyFrame(runTime, false), rocket.x, rocket.y,
                            rocket.width, rocket.height);
                    iter.remove();
                }
            }
        }

        //BATCH END
        batch.end();


        if(TimeUtils.nanoTime() - lastDropTime > 1000000000) spawnRocket();

    }
```

Comment: Maybe check your call to getKeyFrame, you are passing a constant 1 as the amount of seconds an object has spent in the frame. This skews the animation sequence, as I think you'd rather be passing a "stateTime" (accumulation of Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime(), for example). Check out the Animiation example in the libgdx wiki.

Comment: I did set it to runTime aswell but it still runs at the same speed @PeterR

Comment: But are you incrementing/setting your stateTime/runTime correctly? For example, somewhere "on create" set your stateTime to 0, and inside your render method, right before your batch.draw do: stateTime += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime(); then use getKeyFrame(stateTime, false)?

Comment: Yes and passing it into the render method @PeterR

Comment: I think you're not initializing "runTime" at the correct location. Looks like you set it to 0 when you create your gameScreen and it thus accumulates all your games render deltas. When it comes time for your animation, runTime is already so high, the Animation class can't keep up. I think you want a separate counter, initialized to 0 right before your animation begins that accumulates deltas from that point on. Then the Animation class can deduce which frame to show, at the proper speed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're rendering the explosion for only one frame, and then immediately removing that corresponding Rectangle from the game. Right here:

```
            if (tap_Y > rocket.y - 5 && tap_Y < rocket.y + rocket.height + 5) {
                batch.draw(AssetLoader.explosionA.getKeyFrame(runTime, false), rocket.x, rocket.y,
                        rocket.width, rocket.height);
                iter.remove();
            }
```

Also note that you cannot simply use `runTime` for all your explosion animations, because then they will all be in sync with each other, and if it's not a looping animation, then a few seconds into the game they will all simply show the last frame of the animation forever.

There are a number of different approaches you could take for fixing this. Here's one:

Instead of using Rectangle, use a subclass of Rectangle like this that lets you track this individual rocket's animation time and whether it has exploded yet:

```
public class Rocket extends Rectangle {
    public boolean exploded = false;
    public float explosionAge = 0;

    public Rocket(float x, float y, float width, float height) {
        super(x, y, width, height);
    }

    public Rocket(Rectangle rect) {
        super(rect);
    }
}
```

So you would be using this class instead of Rectangle for all your Rockets. Change your `rockets` array to be of type `<Rocket>`.

Then in your loop, instead of drawing and removing a rocket when it's tapped, just flip it's `exploded` boolean on. And then for exploded rockets, you can increment their age, draw their animation, and remove them if the animation is complete. (I'm assuming a non-looping animation here.)

Also, remove the loop where you draw all the rockets. We'll move the drawing step into the bottom loop, so it can decide whether to draw the plain rocket or an explosion:

```
float deltaTime = Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();

Iterator<Rocket> iter = rockets.iterator();
while(iter.hasNext()) {

    Rocket rocket = iter.next();
    rocket.y -= 140 * deltaTime;

    if (!rocket.exploded){

        if(rocket.y + 32 < 0) {
            iter.remove();
            continue;
        }

        if (rocket.x - 5 < tap_X && tap_X < rocket.x + rocket.width + 5) {

            if (tap_Y > rocket.y - 5 && tap_Y < rocket.y + rocket.height + 5) {
                rocket.exploded = true;
                rocket.explosionAge = -deltaTime; //This is so the first frame will start from 0, since deltaTime is added before it's drawn below
            }
        }
    }

    if (rocket.exploded){
        rocket.explosionAge += deltaTime;
        if (rocket.explosionAge > AssetLoader.explosionA.getAnimationDuration()){
            iter.remove();
            continue;
        }

        batch.draw(AssetLoader.explosionA.getKeyFrame(rocket.explostionAge, false), 
            rocket.x, rocket.y, rocket.width, rocket.height);
    } else {
        batch.draw(AssetLoader.rocket, 
            rocket.x, rocket.y, rocket.width, rocket.height);
    }
}
```

This above example is for minimal changes to your current code. But actually I would advise against conflating game world updates and rendering. It makes it harder to debug and find your way around the code if you need to change some behavior. I would instead have an `update` method that updates the positions of the rockets and their explosion states, and a separate `draw` method that simply draws them all.

Comment: Thank you to going to that effort to help me. You really deserve more than just my thanks.